# PHP : String Incrementer

Tags: php

I am making a function similar to auto increment of MySql, but I am using an array of values

```
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
               'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
               'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
               'N','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
               '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',
               '~',-','_');
```

I want to get the next string according to this array. Say I have `"aH?"`, so my next string should be `"aIa"` or if my string is `"???"` so my nest string should be `"aaaa"`. Please suggest me the best and quickest possible method.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you need to use special symbols here? And, by the way, why `aIa` should follow `aH` then?

Comment: Maybe [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) would help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose the best possible method in practice would be using little known property of auto-increment in PHP: it can work with strings, too:

```
$a = 'a';
echo ++$a; // 'b'
echo ++$a; // 'c'

$a = 'z';
echo ++$a; // 'aa'
echo ++$a; // 'ab'

$a = 'az';
echo ++$a; // 'ba'
echo ++$a; // 'bb'

$a = 'zz';
echo ++$a; // 'aaa'
echo ++$a; // 'aab'
```

In fact, one can even mix letters and numbers, like this:

```
$ld = 'a9z9';
echo ++$ld; // 'b0a0'

$ld = 'z9z9';
echo ++$ld; // 'aa0a0'
```

As you see, in case of overflow (`++9`, `++z`) the next symbol (right-to-left) will be incremented as well. And if it's the leftmost one (and was equal to `z`), it becomes 'aa'.

One last thing to say about it: cases are preserved. So that...

```
$mixin = 'Zz9Zz9Zz9';
echo ++$mixin; // 'AAa0Aa0Aa0'
```

Comment: I got the point about incrementing characters and strings but if I want to keep some special characters is there some possibility to carry in single increment of variable.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be something like this (if you just want the values to be auto-incremented and then displayed):

```
<?php
// Set the value of the initial string:
$a = 'a';
// Set the value of the maximum string:
$zzz = 'zzz';
// "Assign $i to $a; while $i is less than the value of $zzz; auto-increment $i;"
for ($i = $a; $i < $zzz; $i++) {
  // Print the incremented value ($i)
  // Print an HTML break (<br/>) for screen formatting
  // Print a new line (\n) for when you view the source code
  print $i . "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most ellegant way to deal with it, but if you really need to use the provided array this function should help you:

```
function getNext($s, $array) {
  static $remember;
  $last = substr($s, -1);
  $key = array_search($last, $array);
  if ($s === "") {
      $remember .= "a";
      return $remember; 
  } else if (isset($array[$key+1])) {
    return substr_replace($s, $array[$key+1], -1) . $remember;
  } else {
    $remember .= "a";
    return getNext(substr($s, 0, -1), $array);
  }
}
```

some output examples:

```
echo getNext("abcd", $array); //abce
echo getNext("??a?", $array); //??ba
echo getNext("???", $array); //aaaa
echo getNext("abc??", $array); //abdaa
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Ziarno's code but if you prefer a non-recursive version here is mine:

```
function inc( $l_str ){
   $alpha = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y
   if( $l_str == '' ) return $alpha[0];
   $letters = array_reverse( str_split( $l_str ) );
   $carry = 1;
   foreach( $letters as $k=>$v ){
      if( $carry == 1 )
         $letters[$k] = $alpha[(array_search($v,$alpha)+1)%count($alpha)];
      if( $letters[$k] != $alpha[0] ) // new letter not an 'a'
         $carry = 0;
   }
   return ($carry == 1 ? $alpha[0] : '').implode(array_reverse($letters));
}
```